# Style bootstrap-slider-rails in form_tag with Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I would like to add a slider to a form partial in Rails 5. I have downloaded the bootstrap-slider-rails gem and included it in the the application.js with

```
//= require bootstrap-slider
```

Furthermore I've added the code

```
<%= f.range_field :price, id: "slider1", :in => 10...100, :class =>"slider" %>
```

in the form partial.

The result is a slider without any styling. I can neither add the current value of the slider nor a legend to the form. I've tried to add some code to the `bootstrap-slider.js` or the `application.js` file but nothing did change. I've never worked with JavaScript before. Can anybody help me with that topic? What do I need to add to the JavaScript files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should call de css and js file like [Bootstrap-Slider-Rails](https://github.com/YourCursus/bootstrap-slider-rails) says

> Require the JavaScript files from your application.js or wherever needed using:

```
//= require bootstrap-slider
```

> Require the CSS files from your application.scss or wherever needed
>   using:

```
*= require bootstrap-slider
```

And in application.js call the jQuery function for slider:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() { 
  $('.slider').slider()
});
```

Comment: When I include the code to the application.js and application.css it doesn't change anything. Do I have to add something else?

Comment: can you check with the input type like text